# how to declare a php variable from a mysql fetch result?

Tags: php, mysql

i know it might be somthing old but i need to declare a variable or that is what i think.

basically i got a table name request and i need to fetch the last value from the column date. which i did in phpMyAdmin. now i need to fecth that exact value and use it as a variable in php.

```
<?php
include 'mydb.php';
require_once 'init.php';
$user_id = $user->data()->id ;
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM request WHERE user_id=   $user_id      ORDER BY latest_request DESC LIMIT 1")  or die(mysql_error());
  $test = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
     {
    echo "<td>" .$row['date']. "</td>" ; 
   }

 ?>


   <?php
 $current_date = echo "<td> .$row['date']. "</td>" ;
 // result im expecing is 2016-10-17 23:53:48
// echo " $current_date" --- will be 2016-10-17 23:53:48
>?
```

but all i get is an empty value, how can i accomplish this

Comment: You can't assign an `echo` to a variable. Do `$current_date = "<td>" .$row['date']. "</td>";`...or probably better `$current_date =  $row['date'];` then build your element where you need it.

Comment: i did exactly as you describe as well and all i get is a blank value, i got the query that echoing the value just fine, but i cant get to declare that same value

Comment: You get an empty `td` or nothing is outputting?

Comment: @nogad `$row` should exist outside the while, it'll be the last record (since limit 1 the `while` isnt really needed)

Comment: true that, just not a useful approach it expecting 1 value

Comment: nothing is outputting, and i guess your right $row doesn't mean anything outside while loop. so i'm still thinking how to accomplish this

Comment: You are probably getting a fatal error then. Check your error logs and/or enable reporting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only one, last row, then maybe better idea would be something like that:

```
  $sql = 'SELECT date FROM request WHERE user_id=   $user_id      ORDER BY     latest_request DESC LIMIT 1';
  $result = mysql_query($sql, $yourDBCon) or die(mysql_error());
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  print_r($row);
```

This solutions brings you only one row.

Also make sure you get anything from sql statment.

Comment: the fetch works it outputs fine, but i need to declare a variable that = to the fetcth result so i can use the variable elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code (based on the fact that you say that the `while()`-loop works, and that you actually get a result with the `$row['date']`:

```
    <?php
    include 'mydb.php';
    require_once 'init.php';
    $user_id = $user->data()->id ;
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM request WHERE user_id = $user_id ORDER BY latest_request DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
        echo $lastdate = '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>' ; 
       }

     echo $current_date = '<td>'.$lastdate.'</td>' ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solve this issues by using pdo insted

```
<?php
$base_datos = DB::getInstance();
 $base_datos->query ("SELECT  req_date FROM request  wHERE user_id =     $user_id  order by req_date desc  limit 1");
 $last_date = $base_datos->results();
 $request_last_date = $last_date[0];
 $c_date =$request_last_date->req_date;

  echo "$c_date";
?>
```

this was to get a value from a table on my database and declared it as a value